# SQL how to encrypt nvarchar column

Tags: sql, sql-server, encryption, sql-server-2014

I have the following code (`SQL server 2014`):

```
    declare @f nvarchar(10) = 'فيدف '
    update mytable set mycol=ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('key', @f) where id = 1

    declare @encrypt varbinary(750) 
    select @encrypt = (select mycol from mytable where id =1)

    select  convert(nvarchar(255),DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('key',@encrypt))
```

The result of the decryption is '??????', why is this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the mycol datatype is varbinary(750) ? I have used exactly your same code and it works

Make sure that :

```
Mycol = varbinary(750)
```

You can not save encrypted value as nvarchar

EDIT: New solution after update of question

Just add N before the text

```
declare @f nvarchar(10) = N'فيدف '
update mytable set mycol=ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('key', @f) where id = 1

declare @encrypt varbinary(750) 
select @encrypt = (select mycol from mytable where id =1)

select  convert(nvarchar(255),DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('key',@encrypt))
```

Comment: I have changed the question... the problem is when I set  @f to arabic characters... any help ?

Comment: Add N before the text you are trying to add. That means: declare @f nvarchar(10) = N'فيدف '